# HOW GROUP BY and ORDER BY going to work in same query

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I know same question were asked many times but not a single solution make any sense to me here is my query if someone can help me out thanks in advance
Following given below query is displaying error.

```
$query = "SELECT  *
    FROM  image
    INNER JOIN  sell_stuff  ON sell_stuff.product_id = image.product_id
    WHERE  Category = 'goods'
    GROUP BY  sell_stuff.product
```

Above query working perfectly but when i try this one i am getting error:

```
$query = "SELECT  *
    FROM  image
    INNER JOIN  sell_stuff  ON sell_stuff.product_id = image.product_id
    WHERE  Category = 'goods'
    GROUP BY  sell_stuff.product_id
    ORDER BY  $sort
    LIMIT  $start,$display";
```

Comment: you have 2 WHERE clauses - this is not right

Comment: oh yup it was mistake let me post right one:

Comment: what do you want to order this thing by?

Comment: I wants to sort it by product price and and date those i stored in $sort variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to use variable with ORDER BY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675874/not-able-to-use-variable-with-order-by)

Comment: Echo out the query, try it in mysql console and share the error message if you not find the error by yourself

Comment: SELECT * FROM image INNER JOIN sell_stuff WHERE sell_stuff.product_id = image.product_id GROUP BY sell_stuff.product_id ORDER BY Date ASC LIMIT 0,15 An error occured in script C:\xampp\htdocs\sort1.php on line 139: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean This is what error i got after echoing out query

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysqli_fetch_assoc%28%29+expects+parameter+1+

Comment: A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` makes no sense, so you are doing right to fix this. The query you have looks rather okay (you should replace `WHERE` by `ON`, though). Maybe your version of MySQL has problems with the column called `DATE`, as this is a keyword. Try with replacing `date` by `"date"` (or with MySQL's backticks instead of the double quotes).

Comment: Thanks Kettner i was using before ON and i tried date with single quotes and doubles too but its not working out

Comment: As Jens said: try the query directly in MySQL rather then through PHP. Do you still get an error?

Answer (score 1):

When you do `SELECT * ... GROUP BY x`, you get one row for each `x`, but you get *unpredictable* values for the other columns of the `*`.  So either of your suggestions is likely to give you garbage results.

In changing from `product` to `product_id`, you *may* have caused a different set of garbage to be delivered.

Fix the `GROUP BY` issue, then we can discuss other issues.

Comment: hey Rick thanks for your valuable suggestion but i did sort out problem it was wrong with my database i defined Date as a column and as you know it is reserved key word in mysql but i am little confuse as you said something about GROUP BY my query is working right at the moment but may be i can learn a bit if you can explain what you meant of your above comment.

Comment: `date` is not fully "reserved"; it is still possible to have a column by that name and not have to add backtics.

Comment: I suggest do a variety of `GROUP BYs` and carefully compare the data received versus the table's data.  Also research "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY".